# Calculating the complement of a knot embedded in $S^3$ via Long Exact sequence of the pair $(S^3,K)$

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology, knot-theory

Calculating the complement of a knot embedded in $S^3$ via Long Exact sequence of the pair $(S^3,K)$.

Let $K$ be a knot embedded in $S^3$. The following sequence of chain complexes is exact:

$0 \rightarrow C(K) \rightarrow C(S^3) \rightarrow C(S^3,K) \rightarrow 0$

Since this short sequence is exact, it induces the following L.E.S. In homology groups:

$0 \rightarrow H_3(S^3) \rightarrow^a H_3(S^3-K) \rightarrow^b H_2(K) \rightarrow^c H_2(S^3) \rightarrow^d H_2(S^3,K) \rightarrow^e H_1(K) \rightarrow^f H_1(S^3) \rightarrow^h H_1(S^3,K) \rightarrow^i H_0(K) \rightarrow^j H_0(S^3) \rightarrow^k H_0(S^3,K) \rightarrow 0$

I proved here: [Use a Meyer-Vietoris sequence to calculate $S^3 - K$ where $K$ is an embedding of $S^1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3289294/use-a-meyer-vietoris-sequence-to-calculate-s3-k-where-k-is-an-embedding-o) that the homology groups are trivial for $i>1$ and infinite cyclic for $i=0,1$.

I am now trying to reach the same result using a different long exact sequence. However, I ran into difficulties right away. The fact that $H_2(K) \cong H_2(S^1) \cong 0$ implies that $H_3(S^3,K) \cong H_3(S^3) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ which is not true. I feel like everything that I've done so far is pretty standard and was hoping that somebody could tell me what is going wrong here. Thanks!

Comment: I'd replace your $H_*(S^3-K)$ by $H_*(S^3,K)$, but what do I know?.....

Comment: Well, usually you know a lot :D. You are right, I should make that substitution, and I will. But it seems the same problem arises >.<

Comment: It's well-known that for compact $K$, $K'\subseteq S^n$, if $K$ and $K'$ are homeomorphic then $H_*(S^n-K)\cong H_*(S^n-K')\cong$ (basically Alexander duality).

Comment: So you are suggesting that if I replace $K$ with a homeomorphic counterpart that will make this calculating not fail?? Perhaps a tubular neighborhood so that $n(K)$ is a solid torus?

Even if i do that, what is wrong with what I did so far? Why am i arriving at the incorrect answer?

Comment: What's wrong with $H_3(S^3,K)\cong H_3(S^3)\cong \mathbb{Z}$?  Another way to get it is $H^3(S^3,K) \cong H^3(S^3,\overline{n(K)})$, where $n(K)$ is an open tubular neighborhood, then by excision $H^3(S^3,K)\cong H^3(S^3-n(K),\partial(S^3-n(K)))$.  $S^3-n(K)$ is a compact connected oriented manifold with boundary, so the relative homology group is generated by its fundamental class.

Comment: Ah, okay. Well I guess that is okay, but it seems I am far away from computing $H_3(S^3-K)$, which was my original goal. I want to compute it using the long exact sequence coming from the pair $(S^3,K)$

Comment: If you use the long exact sequence for $(S^3-n(K),\partial(S^3-n(K)))$, too, you should be able to get it.  (You'll need to know what some of the maps actually do, like how the connecting homomorphism is from taking the boundary of an underlying cycle for the homology class.)

Comment: Hmm. A bit above my paygrade at the moment ;-/